# What are some good methods or steps to debug a segmentation fault in Perl?

Tags: perl, debugging, segmentation-fault

There are two cases where my code won't cause a [segmentation fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault):

1. When I use [Smart::Comments](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Smart::Comments) in at least one place
2. Run through the debugger.

I've tracked it down to this call:

```
$action->{breakdown} 
    = join( ' '
          ,  each_pair { 
                my ( $name, $length ) = @_;
                return "x$length" if $name eq 'FILLER';
                push @$field_list_ref, $name;
                return "A$length";

            } @$field_def_ref
    );
```

where `each_pair` is defined in another module as:

```
sub each_pair (&@) { 
    my $block   = shift;
    return unless @_;
    my $caller  = caller();
    my $aref    = qualify( 'a', $caller );
    my $bref    = qualify( 'b', $caller );
    my @results;
    my $pairs   = 0;

    for ( my $index = 0; $index < $#_; $index += 2 ) { 
        $pairs++;
        my @pair                 = @_[$index..($index+1)];
        no strict 'refs';
        local ( $$aref, $$bref ) = @pair;
        push @results, $block->( @pair );
    }
    return wantarray || $pairs != 1 ? @results : shift @results;
}
```

- Now I know that I can just replace each_pair with [List::MoreUtils::natatime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::MoreUtils#natatime) (although I hear that has some bugs), they have just recently allowed this module into our environment, and I'm still interested in why this call is causing a segmentation fault--or what other Perl programmers due to debug segmentation faults.

I've lost a bit of time on this.

---

#### EDIT

I have other modules using this function, some expect to be able to use `$a` and `$b`, also it's working elsewhere in the same module, for another list. I can change this invocation of it, I can change it for this file, but changing it for every place that uses it successfully, is probably more changes than I would be allowed to make at this late hour.

Comment: Yeah.  Damian modules for production code?  Not a very good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segmentation faults are exceptionally rare in Perl. I can't recall the last time I encountered one.

Debuggers are intrusive enough that it's not particularly surprising that the code would behave differently there, though it's certainly frustrating. `Smart::Comments` uses source filters which (as we all know) are *evil*. Poking into the source for Smart::Comments, I see that it uses List::Util which normally uses an [XS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XS_%28Perl%29) implementation. It's possible that `List::Util` is what "fixes" your problem. Try using `List::Util` directly but not `Smart::Comments`. That won't solve anything, but it might take the uncertainty of a source filter out of the equation.

Unfortunately, your problem seems to be not with the code itself but with unexpected interactions between different things. You can't really trigger a segmentation fault directly in Perl. The root must be in either perl itself or XS code. If you can reduce it to a small but complete sample others might be able to reproduce and isolate the problem.

Comment: I checked my diff of dumps I took of %INC, List::Util appeared in both lists. Thanks all the same.

Answer (score 4):

As to general debugging steps, you could always run the Perl interpreter under `gdb`.  The chances of seeing anything educational aren't necessarily that hot, but I've done it a couple times, and it may have even helped once.

Comment: You need to use gdb and valgrind.  Valgrind will make your program die closer to the actual error.

Answer (score 3):

I will echo [chaos' concern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172476/what-are-some-good-methods-or-steps-to-debug-a-seg-fault-in-perl/1172535#1172535) with the `each_pair` function.  What happens if you use the following implementation?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

sub each_pair(&@);

my $field_def_ref  = [ qw( FILLER 5 NOTFILLER 6 ) ];
my $field_list_ref;

print join(' ' => each_pair {
    my ($name, $length) = @_;
    return "x$length" if $name eq 'FILLER';
    push @$field_list_ref, $name;
    return "A$length";
} @$field_def_ref ), "\n";

print Dumper $field_list_ref;

sub each_pair( &@ ) {
    my $code = shift;
    my @results;

    for my $i ( 0 .. $#_/2 ) {
        push @results, $code->( shift, shift );
    }

    return @results;
}
__END__
```

Answer (score 3):

Segfaults can come from memory bugs in C written external modules bound with XS.

I recommend running your script in [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to spot the error:

```
valgrind perl ./yourfaultyscript.pl
```

Comment: Looks interesting, but it doesn't look like it runs on AIX.

Comment: Yep, linux only I'm afraid.
Do you experience the same issue on a linux box?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I can't figure out why your `each_pair()` is doing this:

```
my $caller  = caller();
my $aref    = qualify( 'a', $caller );
my $bref    = qualify( 'b', $caller );
```

or this:

```
    no strict 'refs';
    local ( $$aref, $$bref ) = @pair;
```

and referencing operations that require you to turn off `strict refs` seem immediately suspect in a segfaulting situation.

What happens if you disable all that?

Comment: So how would a debugger or more debugging-related code make or break that?

Comment: Sometimes debugging code moves stuff around so that bugs don't get triggered.  That's the nature of the heisenbug. http://catb.org/jargon/html/H/heisenbug.html

Comment: He's trying to make `$a` and `$b` aliases for the pairs (like `sort` does), put them in the caller's namespace for use in the block, and localize them to avoid collisions with any other use of those variables. Disabling `strict 'refs'` just allows the use of symbolic references. I wouldn't normally suspect if of being related to a segfault. However `qualify` (which I'm not familiar with) might, as I suspect there's deep XS magic going on there.