# How do I check bug history on a module in the Perl core?

Tags: perl, perl-core

Quite recently, I asked a question about debugging a seg fault: [What are some good methods or steps to debug a seg fault in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172476/what-are-some-good-methods-or-steps-to-debug-a-seg-fault-in-perl). Somebody mentioned that [Symbol](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Symbol) had some deep XS magic in it.

I'm wondering if I can find a bug history for a Perl core module. I tried looking on [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/), but the change documentation is kept at the project level and not the module level.

See, we run Perl 5.8.2 and Symbol v1.05 and I'm just wondering if one of our issues could be related to a bugfix that occurred between that and the current version.

Comment: No, they said they *suspected* Symbol (in particular, Symbol::qualify) had deep XS magic, but it isn't true; Symbol is pure perl and not that complicated. If you are having trouble with segfaults, I strongly recommend you just upgrade to 5.8.9 before even bothering looking further.

Comment: @ysth: Yeah, I browsed it since then, and it was pure perl (and yes, not that complex). Second though, you don't know my shop. It's a everything-new-should-be-written-in-Java type of perl-using shop. There's no way I could get them to jump from 5.8.2 to 5.8.9 in time for this. And likely, the only way I could make the case in the future would be if I can nail something like this down to a specific bug fixed in the new version.

Comment: @Axeman: I understand completely, but there was a huge effort to get rid of segfaults between 5.8.2 and 5.8.9.

Comment: @ysth: Well *that's* something I can tell them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about looking in the [perl source repository](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/history/HEAD:/lib/Symbol.pm)?

Comment: Wasn't aware of that resource? Thanks.

Comment: @ Sinan Ünür: I'm guessing it was *the* answer--just wish the version numbers were a little more clear on that page. But I've bookmarked it. One of the problems of living on the lagging edge is that sometimes problems that you run into have been solved already in subsequent modules. We run into trouble on our recent Java-bleeding-edge stance, and we run into trouble on Perl doing the opposite. Both have their problems.

Comment: @Axeman BTW, the `perl???delta.pod` files can be accessed on line http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perl583delta

Comment: @Sinan Ünür: Thanks again, I have looked at the deltas before, if the info is there, I guess I skipped it this time.

Comment: @Axeman No, I don't think the information is there. I pointed them out for future reference (because trying to browse the `git` repository is frustrating for me as well.